# Opening multiple files in Python before closing previous?

Tags: python

I have a noob python question... so bear with me.

Can I open multiple files before closing the previos.
So... can I run

```
import os
files=[]
for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    files.append(open(file,'w'))
```

Then edit each file as I want and finish with

```
for file in files:
    file.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to run the code?

Comment: Ya I just wan't sure if it was logically incorrect

Comment: You _can_ do this, but it doesn’t seem like a good approach. Why not just open each file, process it, and then close it?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will certainly work but the recommended way would be to use `contextmanager` so that the files gets handled seamlessly. For example

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        # do some actions on the file
```

The `with` statement will take care of closing the file for you.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: But a it is written here, this will close each file *before* opening the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems legit and works fine.

Doing operations would be hard for you this way. the list "files" doesn't contain the filenames. You would not know which file is what.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to open each file using `open` and later `close` all of them. However, you will want to make sure all of your files are closed properly.

Normally, you would do this for one file:

```
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    do_something_with_the_file(f)
# the file is closed here, regardless of what happens
# i.e. even in case of an exception
```

You could do the same with multiple files:

```
with open(filename1,'w') as f1, open(filename2,'w') as f2:
    do_something_with_the_file(f)
# both files are closed here
```

Now, if you have N files, you could write your own context manager, but that would probably be an overkill. Instead, I would suggest:

```
open_files = []
try:
    for filename in list_of_filenames:
        open_files.append(open(filename, 'w'))

    # do something with the files here

finally:
    for file in open_files:
        file.close()
```

BTW, your own code deltes the contents of all files in the current directory. I am not sure you wanted that:

```
for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    files.append(open(file,'w')) # open(file,'w') empties the file!!!
```

Maybe you wanted `open(file, 'r')` or `open(file, 'a')` instead? (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)